# Power BI DAX Calculation based on month selected in slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, slicers

I need several measures in my report. The measure I want to start with is count of distinct ID four months before the month I selected on (e.g if I select on Aug 2018, the calculation would be all distinct ID before 30/04/2018). The reason I'm doing this is later on I also want to use this same slicer to work on count of ID within the four month period based on the selection.

Here is my DAX Calculation with comments:

```
Count four months ago =
// Find the end date of the month
VAR end_of_last_quarter =
    FORMAT ( EOMONTH ( MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ), -4 ), "dd/mm/yyyy" )
RETURN
    // Count distinct ID on or before that date
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Report Data'[Id] ),
        FORMAT ( 'Report Data'[REPORT DATE], "d/mm/yyyy" )
            <= FORMAT ( end_of_last_quarter, "d/mm/yyyy" )
    )
        & " Reports before "
        & end_of_last_quarter
```

However after checking this calculation, it seems it only gives me the number of counts in the month I selected:

[image]

The screenshot tells me there are 12 report in Apr 2018, rather than the right number before 31/12/2017.

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Comment: In `FORMAT('Report Data'[REPORT DATE], "d/mm/yyyy")<=FORMAT(end_of_last_quarter, "d/mm/yyyy")` you are doing order comparison of strings, not of dates. Consider removing the `FORMAT`. Similarly, remove the FORMAT from `end_of_last_quarter`, so you are working with dates rather than strings.

Comment: @Mankarse Thanks for the suggestion. It works OK and give me the correct number. However when I want to use a matrix visualization and put a field on the row and this measure on the value, it won't give me proper breakdown (i.e. sum of count for each category is not equal to total).